# How to implement Datasource property on custom controls?

Tags: asp.net

Hii,

I m working in Asp.net 2.0 with C#.... I have a custom control and i have to use 'Datasource' property which is exactly like a repeater having. Any idea regarding this pls help me.

Answer (score 1):

Any public property with a setter will be exposed in the markup:

```
public class MyControl : UserControl
{
   public object DataSource {get; set;}
}
```

This will allow you to set the DataSource property either through the HTML or in code.

Is that what you meant?